# How to covert decoded url to a PHP object?

Tags: php, forms, object, post, urlencode

I have big form and had to serialize a part of it before sending to PHP to get rid of the limitation of "max_input_vars"

I want to convert the encoded value with PHP as orginal $_POST value.

I guess all i need to convert it to an object after decoded the post value but couldn't found the way.

Any help is really appreciated.

Best Regards

UPDATE: Here are the codes;

here is how I encode the form with javascript

```
    //searialize the form
    serialize_form = $(thisForm).serialize();
    serialize_form = "serialize_form="+encodeURIComponent(serialize_form);
```

Then in my php file;

```
    $formValues = urldecode( $_POST["serialize_form"] );
```

My php code was working fine before encode the serialized form, all need to have the same object with php after urldecode.

Comment: You're gonna have to show us some code and what you've tried to solve the problem before we can help.

Comment: I've just updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns something like this (taken from example on that page):

```
single=Single2&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio2
```

PHP has a function called [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) that works like this:

```
void parse_str ( string $str [, array &$arr ] )
```

Usage example:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

So call `parse_str` on your input and you can get either a list of variables or an array. I would do an array.

Comment: OK, It turns out parse_str is also using the same max_input_vars value. Now I am having this error;

<b>Warning</b>:  parse_str(): Input variables exceeded 1000.

Comment: Well the `max_input_vars` is there for security but if you really need to you can change it in php.ini. Another question to ask is why you need a form with that many inputs rather than how to handle it.

Comment: It is a really long story, i'd use json if i start the project today. Anyway it is a dynamic content builder and if user adds many things the form may reach that level. I've already put an alert that notifies the user he should update the max_input_vars value via php.ini but i'm searching a way to by-pass this.

Comment: It's not something the user can change. But think about this: if you're making a form with over 1000 elements, you're doing something wrong. I would put a hard limit on it way below 1000.